# How to use backtick command result with sed?

Tags: bash, sed, quoting

I want to replace the version in my code using `git rev-parse HEAD` with template string `%VERSION%` in a source file.

For simplicity I will use `date` as version command in this question.

Given `test.txt`

```
$ echo "This is test-%VERSION%." > test.txt
$ cat test.txt
This is test-%VERSION%.
```

Expect

```
This is test-Sat Dec  2 16:48:59 +07 2017.
```

These are failed try

```
$ echo "This is test-%VERSION%." > test.txt
$ sed -i 's/%VERSION/`date`/' test.txt && cat test.txt
This is test-`date`%.

$ echo "This is test-%VERSION%." > test.txt
$ DD=`date` sed -i 's/%VERSION/$DD/' test.txt && cat test.txt
This is test-$DD%.

$ echo "This is test-%VERSION%." > test.txt
$ DD=`date` sed -i "s/%VERSION/$DD/" test.txt && cat test.txt
This is test-%.
```

Do I really need to use `xargs` ?

Comment: Use single (not double) quotes for substitution.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed `$(...)` within double-quotes, but not in single-quotes:

```
sed -i "s/%VERSION%/$(date)/" test.txt && cat test.txt
```

(Same as `` `...` `` but you shouldn't use that obsolete syntax, `$(...)` is better.)

---

Btw, for testing purposes, it's better to use `sed` without `-i`,
so the original file is not modified:

```
sed "s/%VERSION%/$(date)/" test.txt
```

---

As a side note, and this is a completely different discussion,
but worth mentioning here.
This may look like it should work but it doesn't, and you may wonder why:

```
DD=$(date) sed -i "s/%VERSION%/$DD/" test.txt && cat test.txt
```

Why it doesn't work?
Because the `$DD` embedded in the `"..."` is evaluated at the time the command is executed.
At that time the value of `DD` is *not* set to the output of `$(date)`.
In the `"..."` it will have whatever value it had before executing the command.
For the `sed` process, the value `DD` with the output of `$(date)` is visible,
but `sed` doesn't use that, because why would it.
The `"..."` passed to `sed` is evaluated by the shell, not by `sed`.

Comment: More robustly is to always use `sed 's/%VERSION%/'"$(date)"'/'` so you only expose the part of the script to the shell that you want exposed and so don't have to worry about `$`, for example, appearing in the other parts.

Answer (score 1):

Use double-quotes to do the substitution and avoid using the outdated `` construct but rather use the [`$(..)` syntax for Command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst)

```
sed -i "s/%VERSION%/$(date)/" file
```

Also another way if you just want to use the single quotes, would be to wrap the substitution part in double-quotes and then single-quote on top of it, something like `sed 's/%VERSION%/'"$(date)"'/' file` which is less efficient than simply double-quoting the entire substitution string.

Comment: Thank for the answer, too bad that I can only accept one answer.